# In the General Number Field Sieve, can we estimate the size of the matrix in terms of the number being factored?

Tags: number-theory, factoring, cryptography, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

One of the last steps of GNFS is to solve a large matrix-vector equation (usually using the Block Lanczos algorithm or the Block Wiedemann algorithm). The matrix for the most recent RSA number factored (RSA-220, completed in May 2016) was an $M\times M$ square where $M=192796550$, making this a cumbersome part of the algorithm. Can we estimate how big $M$ will be for some number $N$ that we wish to factor? Is there an asymptotic relation between $M$ and $N$ in $\mathcal{O}(\cdot )$ notation?

Comment: Is there a relationship between $M$ and $N$? How does one obtain $M$?

Comment: It is obtained after the sieving step of the GNFS algorithm, which is done after polynomial selection. It is a rather involved procedure, which is why I don't know the answer to the question :)

Comment: The optimal size depends on the magnitude of the number to be factored. If we would reduce the size of the matrix, it would be harder to find factorization-relations, hence the size is chosen as an optimal compromise of the size of the prime factor base and the size of the matrix.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. Is there some more concrete relation? For example $M$ cannot just be 1, right? Is there a *minimum* value $M$ must be? Such as $\Omega(N^3/ b)$ where $N$ is the number being factored and $b$ is the size of the base? If not, is there at least some empirical data we can look at for the sizes of $M$ used for factorizations that have been completed?

Comment: I am not an expert at this topic, but studying the theory of B-smooth numbers should be helpful. I do not know how the optimal value can be calculated, but I think most programs using the quadratic sieve use the formula for the optimal value.

Comment: Reading the reports on factorization of RSA-768 and RSA-220, it appears that finding the "optimal" value for $M$ in the GNFS is a very open question, and an active area of research. They over-sieved for RSA-768 so that the matrix step would be easier, and they say this was partly to study the trade-off between over-sieving and making the matrix step too cumbersome. They said this topic would be the subject of future papers. Based on this, I highly doubt there's any "optimal" value, but surely there is ***minimum*** value or at least an asymptotic lower bound isn't there? E.g. $M$ cannot be 1.

Comment: @Peter: Also, what is the formula for the optimal value for the quadratic sieve?

Comment: As I said, I am not an expert. Maybe, the optimal value is only known for small numbers because of experience with factorizations already done and for larger numbers it is not known, I can only guess.

Comment: @Peter: I am asking for the minimum value, or an asymptotic lower bound. Optimum value is still an active area of research and open question. But you say there's a formula for the optimal value for the qsieve. What is it?

Comment: Maybe, I am wrong. I assumed that a formula is known because the programs I used calculate the size of the factor base. I do not actually know a formula, but maybe wikipedia or mathworld mention such a formula.

Comment: I checked those.